# Memory issues with new version of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, server, windows-services, windows-server-2012, production-environment

I'm using Mongodb on my Windows server 2012 for more than two years. Since the last update some weird issues started to happen which in the end lead to usage of the entire RAM memory.

The service Iv'e configured for Mongodb is as follows:

```
logpath=d:\data\log\mongod.log 
dbpath=d:\data\db
storageEngine=wiredTiger
rest=true

#override port
port=27017

#configsvr = true
shardsvr = true
```

And in order to limit the Cache memory usage Iv'e added the following line:

```
wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=10
```

And this is where the weird stuff started happening. When I check the task manager it says that now Mongodb is really limited to 10GB as I defined in the service but it is actually using a lot more than 10GB.

In the first image you can see the memory consumption sorted by RAM consumption

[image]

While in fact the machine I'm using has 28GB in total
[image]

This crazy consumption leads to failure in the scripts I'm running, even the most basic ones, even when I only run simple queries like 'count' or 'distinct', I believe that this is a direct results of the memory consumption.

When I checked the log files I saw that there are many open connections that even when the session ends it indicates that still the same amount of connections is opened:

[image]

So in the end I have two major questions:
1. Is there a way of solving this issue without downgrading the Mongodb version?
2. The config file looks right? is everything there is necessary?

Comment: You should have opened a new question when you include your new connection findings and change the question, instead of change your question and un-accept answer.  1) You need to specify what versions of MongoDB involved. i.e upgrade from to version. Regarding connection, it's a connection pooling, you need to include how you are opening connections. i.e. driver language and version. 2) See [Config Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/). Depends on your deployment use case, you most likely don't need `shardsvr` and `rest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory usage in [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#wiredtiger-storage-engine) is a two-level cache:

- First is the WiredTiger cache as controlled by `--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB`
- Second is the Operating System filesystem cache. MongoDB automatically uses all free memory that is not used by the WiredTiger cache or by other processes

See also [WiredTiger memory usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use)

For OS filesystem cache, MongoDB doesn't manage the memory it uses directly - it lets the OS manage it. Windows will try to use every last scrap of physical memory if it can - but lots of it should and will be thrown out if other processes request memory.

An alternative is to run `mongod` in a container (e.g. lxc, cgroups, Docker, etc.) that does not have access to all of the RAM available in a system.

Having said the above:

- You are also running another database in the server i.e. `mysqld`. MongoDB, like some databases will perform better on a dedicated server to reduce memory contention.
- Task Manager shows `mongod` is using 10GB, although the machine is using up to ~28GB. This may or may not be `mongod` as you have other processes as well.

Useful resources:

- [FAQ: Memory diagnostics for WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics-for-the-wiredtiger-storage-engine)
- [FAQ: MongoDB Cache Handling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching)
- [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#production-notes)